# How to conditionally loop an animation in Framer Motion?

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I created an animation using Framer Motion's `useAnimation()`. I want to loop the animation using `while` loop with the condition `!isOpen` to run the animation endlessly until the user clicks the element. However, when `isOpen` state is true the screen freezes and it endlessly `console.log('hello')`.

How can run the animation endlessly without freezing my screen? If there is a more appropriate approach other than this, please let me know. Thanks!

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
const controls = useAnimation();

const idleAnimation = async () => {
    while (!isOpen) {
        await controls.start({
            scaleY: [1, 0.75, 1.1],
            transition: {
                duration: 0.5,
                ease: "easeIn",
                delay: 1
            }
        });

        await controls.start({
            y: [0, -75, 0],
            transition: {
                ease: "easeInOut",
                duration: 1,
                y: {
                    duration: 0.85,
                }
            }
        });

        await controls.start({
            scaleY: [1.1, 0.95, 1],
            transition: {
                duration: 0.5,
                ease: "easeOut"
            }
        });

        console.log('hello')
    }
};

<motion.div
    animate={isOpen ? null : controls}
    style={{
        originY: "100%"
    }}
    onClick={() => { setIsOpen(true) }}
    className="Gift"
>
    // Code
</motion.div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient way, but you can run it this way.

```js
const runAnimation = async () => {
     await controls.start({
            scaleY: [1, 0.75, 1.1],
            transition: {
                duration: 0.5,
                ease: "easeIn",
                delay: 1
            }
        });

        await controls.start({
            y: [0, -75, 0],
            transition: {
                ease: "easeInOut",
                duration: 1,
                y: {
                    duration: 0.85,
                }
            }
        });

        await controls.start({
            scaleY: [1.1, 0.95, 1],
            transition: {
                duration: 0.5,
                ease: "easeOut"
            }
        });
        if(open) runAnimation(); // Restart the animation series once completed
};

useEffect(() => {
    runAnimation();
}, [open]);
```

However if you don't mind all animations running at once or if you want to tweak it a bit, you can make it more efficient by using the repeat function.

```js
await controls.start({
  scaleY: [1, 0.75, 1.1],
  transition: {
    duration: 0.5,
    ease: "easeIn",
    repeat: Infinity,
    repeatType: "reverse",
    delay: 1
  }
});

await controls.start({
  y: [0, -75, 0],
  transition: {
    ease: "easeInOut",
    duration: 1,
    repeat: Infinity,
    repeatType: "reverse",
    y: {
      duration: 0.85,
    }
 }
});

await controls.start({
  scaleY: [1.1, 0.95, 1],
  transition: {
    duration: 0.5,
    repeat: Infinity,
    repeatType: "reverse",
    ease: "easeOut"
  }
});
```